# javascript user value convert to format

Tags: javascript, date, time

```
    var t = "Jan. 20, 2017 20:28:53"
    var s = t.format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S");
    alert(s);
```

How I convert the value into the

> 01/20/2017 20:28:53

this format.Please help me. Thank you...

Comment: try `new Date(t)` look up javascript Date object for formats

Comment: sorry friends.I can't use new Date(t) function. any other option for getting this output.

Comment: And why can you not use Date() which is the correct way of doing it? If not, you will have to write a function that rips apart the string and build the format yourself. Have fun.

Comment: It is an order from my superior

Comment: Well enjoy parsing the dates yourself.

Comment: @epascarello If I am doing that new Date(t) function then how i continue with that.please help me.and provide the complete code

Comment: @bobmarti—don't do that, the format isn't supported by ECMA-262 so you're relying on implementations to support a non–standard format.

Answer (score 0):

Try the moment library
http://momentjs.com/

You can do

```
moment('Jan. 20, 2017 20:28:53').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
```

returns -> '01/20/2017 20:28:53 PM'

Comment: thanks for your answer.but i can't implement the project with momentjs library function

Comment: Using a parser, you should also provide the format of the string, otherwise you're letting the parser guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var t = "Jan. 20, 2017 20:28:53"

var test = new Date(t);

var str = [addTrailingZero(test.getMonth()+1), addTrailingZero(test.getDate()+1),test.getFullYear()].join('/')
+ ' ' +
[addTrailingZero(test.getHours()+1), addTrailingZero(test.getMinutes()+1),
addTrailingZero(test.getSeconds()+1)
].join(':');

alert(str);

function addTrailingZero(date) {
    if ( date < 10 ) {
    return '0' + date;
  }

  return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is not recommended due to the many differences between implementations. Parsing of a string in a format like 'Jan. 20, 2017 20:28:53' is implementation dependent and may result in an invalid date.

If you want to create a Date from a string, use a bespoke function or a library, there are plenty to choose from.

But you don't need to create a Date to reformat a date string, you can just reformat the string:

```js
function reformatDatestring(s) {
  function z(n) {return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
  var months = 'jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec'.split(' ');
  var b = s.split(/[\.,]?\s/);
  var month = months.indexOf(b[0].toLowerCase());
  return z(month+1) + '/' + z(b[1]) + '/' + b[2] + ' ' + b[3];
}

console.log(reformatDatestring('Jan. 20, 2017 20:28:53'));
```